# Populate HTML with firebase products data and get total amount

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im populating a custom HTML to create a "cart" with firebase data, by doing this:

```
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {

      var itemName = childSnapshot.key;
      var price = childSnapshot.val().price;
      var qty = childSnapshot.val().qty;
      var html = '';
      html += '<a class="list-group-item">';

      html +=  itemName + ' ($' + price + ")" ;

      html += '<span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right" id="' + itemName + '">';
      html += '<input type="text" class="width-input form-control" value="' + qty + '">' ;
      html += '</span>';
      html += '</a>';

      $("#list-items").append(html);
```

I get a list of items as expected:

[image: firebase populated list]

the final html of each item is:

```
<a class="list-group-item">
   Bananas ($7.50)
   <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right" id="Bananas">
       <input type="text" class="width-input form-control" value="8">
   </span>
</a>
```

Now, I don't know how to retrieve each item price and quantity to do the final math for the cost also how can I get the new quantity if a user changes the value on the text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already looping through the results you can use a variable and add the price each iteration.

```
    totalPrice += price;
```

or

```
    totalPrice += (price * qty);
```

If they change the quantity use a onChange() listener on the input element and rerun the calculation.

Comment: So true, my first idea was to do something to avoid updating the database before the user makes all necessary changes, I end up using a onfocus() listener that triggers a function which as  focusout() listener, in that way i can get the Input in the field and update the database once the user leaves the field.